# How to detect if javascript mailto failed (eg no email client configured)

Tags: javascript, email

I have found that if I use this code:

```
function emailer() {
  return window.open("mailto:someone@gmail.com?subject=whatever it is")
}

emailer();
```

On a computer with no email client configured, well, it basically doesn't work.  In that case I would like to find out if there was an error and paste the text to send into an element in my page and prompt user to paste this message into their email and send to me - in this slightly less convenient way.

How would I detect if there was an error on using mailto?

UPDATE:

I will wait a little longer for responses but it looks like it is not possible.  I think I will have to offer simpler alternative every time and make it obvious to user to use this if automated email option fails.

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. The E-Mail window will be outside your reach, and you will have no way of checking whether it exists.

Comment: Not possible. Not only can you not tell if the email client is configured, you also can't tell whether the user simply closes the mail window without sending. Or whether they change the address before sending. Or any number of other actions they could do that would break your expected flow.

Comment: I think there may be a way forward by triggering mailto: URI schemes using iframes instead. But IE (as usual) is giving me a few minor test problems thus far. Will let you know if I find a reliable cross-browser way of doing this, when I get a chance to look further into it.